# Customers ordering out of stock products

Tags: stock, inventory, magento2.3.0

I have my store set up so that out of stock items do not show up. For some odd reason every so often a customer is able to purchase a product that is out of stock. When I look that item up on my computer on the site it doesn't even show up. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: which magento version you are using please share let me know

Comment: Make sure on the products level that you don't allow backorders and verify your indexers run on update by schedule.